# MacOS Ventura 13.1 /bin/ln can run in background?

Tags: macos, startup, ventura

While reviewing my apps running in background on my **M1 MacOS Ventura 13.1** I saw that `/bin/ln` has *"run in background"* switched on. Why? Does `/bin/ln` need this? Moreover, Mac says "this comes from unidentified developer". Should I be worried that this is some kind of malware? I've tried to compare md5 checksum (*f95cbde002ce4816e01c64511f3897b7*), but I can't find the original one online or locally? The folder is not backed up automatically in Time Machine. I've briefly reviewed the contents of the binary and it does have the `Apple Code Signing Certification Authority (...)`

On the other hand, all files in `/bin` have been created at the same time (02.12.2022) and haven't been modified since.
Should I be worried or this is some oversight by Apple while upgrading or something like this?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: /bin/ln should be part of the system's read-only volume; so I wouldn't worry too much about why it is the way it is: however, I'd worry about why it's running at all.

Comment: I turned it off, so it shouldn't run in the background. Any ideas why it wants to? Do you have 13.1 Ventura and can check if you also have it in `Settings > General > Login Items > Allow in the Background` and what's it's md5?

Comment: Ah: right, now I understand. No, it's not the Settings list of allowed processes here (Though that area is still a work in progress for Apple.) I don't think it's a problem.

Comment: oh, ok thanks. Is your md5 same as mine?

Comment: If you have doubts, I'd reinstall the OS. (Leaving your files in place).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I think I know what is going on here. Do you have Docker installed, by any chance?

Docker is (with permission from the user) installing a file at `/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.docker.socket.plist` which uses `/bin/ln` to make a link via the command `/bin/ln -s -f /Users/<username>/.docker/run/docker.sock /var/run/docker.sock`.

If you have Docker installed, then this is scary looking but harmless.

If you do not have Docker installed, I'd suggest looking through the files in places like `/Library/LaunchDaemons`, `/Library/LaunchAgents`, `~/Library/LaunchAgents`, et cetera, to see if you can find one that is calling `ln` and figure out if it is of concern or not.

Good luck!

Comment: Yes, I do have docker installed. Wow, that's some great investigation. How did you find all this out?

Comment: Good catch ! One question though, Docker might use commands like `cp`, `ls`, etc, are they all listed "run in background" ?

Comment: Nope. Just this one. My assumption is because this is (1) a specific command that they want to ensure is run before Docker starts, and (2) it needs admin provledfes to run correctly. The mechanics of why this solution versus other potential ones is beyond my knowledge though!

Comment: @Paploo I also have docker installed, but `echo bin/ln | md5 gives 9b77d2ef63ed96afc5777d5b9b54982c` which is not the same?