# Why do I see “ln” listed in the login items?

Tags: macos, launchd, login-items, launch-services

I'm currently using macOS Ventura 13.1 on my i5 Macbook Pro 2020. After updating to this version, some unexpected behavior has arose, such as ["Steam" added items that can run in the background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74898082/steam-added-items-that-can-run-in-the-background). I was able to fix that issue by removing Steam related file from `/User/user_name/Library/LaunchAgents`.

Now, I realized something interesting. I have `ln` on the “Allow in the Background” list. Although it says “item from unidentified developer”, the source directory is directly `/bin/ln`. If there's no such reverse engineering or similar, I believe it's most likely safe. It's literally the `ln` command to link files. After surfing a bit through other people's problems with the same page, I figured that I'm the only one with the `ln` listed.

My question is simple: Why do I see `ln` listed here meanwhile other people don't have it?

[image]

Comment: It says it's "unidentified", because unix commands aren't 'signed'. Ventura has revised the way this panel works and what it shows, and I think it still needs some work.

Answer (score 2):

It's related to **Docker for macOS**.  It's harmless.  ([more info](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/452090/85092))